# selection based on certain condition

Tags: sql, oracle

select col1, col2, col3 from tab1

```
rownum col1 col2 col3 
1      1    10    A
2      1    15    B
3      1    0     A
4      1    0     C
5      2    0     B
6      3    20    C
7      3    0     D
8      4    10    B
9      5    0     A
10     5    0     B
```

Output required is

```
col1 col2 col3 
1    10   A
1    15   B
2    0    B
3    20   C
4    10   B
5    0    A
5    0    B
```

col1 and col2 are my lookup/joining columns columns, if col2 is having "non zero" data then I need to ignore/filter record with 0 (in above example I need to filter record rownum  3 4 and 7) If col2 is not having any data other than "non zero" in that case only select record with 0 (in above example col1 with value 1 and 5).

I m trying to write sql for this. Hope I have mentioned requirement clearly, please let me know if you need anything more from my side. Seem to have gone blank in this case.

Database - Oracle 10g

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about testing `col2` in a group based on one of the other columns. Which column are you grouping on?

Comment: In your second part, do you mean `col1 with value 2 and 5`?

Comment: @MitchWheat I was trying for self join with one set as zero and other one non zero. Then taking into considertion based on minus considition pull record from main table.

Comment: @Barmar need to filter records with rownum having values (3,4,7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM (SELECT col1,
             col2,
             col3,
             sum(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) sum_col2
      FROM tab1)
WHERE (  (   sum_col2 <> 0
         AND col2 <> 0)
      OR sum_col2 = 0)
```

If col2 can be negative and the requirement is that the sum of col2 has "non-zero" data then the above is OK, however, if it is the requirement that any col2 value has "non-zero" data then it should be changed to:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col3
FROM (SELECT col1,
             col2,
             col3,
             sum(abs(col2)) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) sum_col2
      FROM tab1)
WHERE (  (   sum_col2 <> 0
         AND col2 <> 0)
      OR sum_col2 = 0)
```

Comment: It gets an error at sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69bac/12. I get the same error with my query. Why is `col1` an invalid identifier?

Comment: [This Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69bac/14) has the right one @barmar ddl has double quotes for columns.. So it has to be followed in dmls too..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tab1 t1
JOIN (SELECT "col1", MAX("col2") AS max2
      FROM tab1
      GROUP BY "col1") t2
ON t1."col1" = t2."col1"
WHERE ((max2 = 0 AND "col2" = 0)
       OR
       (max2 != 0 AND "col2" != 0))
ORDER BY "rownum"
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/69bac/19)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer above, I made the same changes myself.